# How can I create a table within a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, pdf

i'm having trouble on making a basic pdf document with a table in it in python, and i'm wondering how i can get my table to show on the PDF, because i'm unsure on how it's not showing, here's the code for reference.

```
import time
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, landscape, letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Image, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("code challenge1.pdf",pagesize=letter,
                        rightMargin=72,leftMargin=72,
                        topMargin=72,bottomMargin=18)
Story=[]
 
formatted_time = time.ctime()
full_name = "Mike Driscoll"
address_parts = ["411 State St.", "Marshalltown, IA 50158"]
 
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Justify', alignment=TA_JUSTIFY))
ptext = '<font size=12>%s</font>' % formatted_time
 
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Normal"]))
Story.append(Spacer(1, 12))


data = [
["Activity", "Times/wk”, "Time of day", "Description"],
["B", "01", "ABCD", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"],
["E", "02", "CDEF", "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB"],
["E", "03", "SDFSDF", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC"],
["e", "04", "SDFSDF", "DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD"],
["x", "05", "GHJGHJGHJ", "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE"],
]
 
style = TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.red),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.blue),
                       ('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                       ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.green),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ])
        
s = getSampleStyleSheet()
s = s["BodyText"]
s.wordWrap = 'CJK'
data2 = [[Paragraph(cell, s) for cell in row] for row in data]
t=Table(data2)
t.setStyle(style)
 
Story.append(t)
ptext = '<font size=12>I wanted to code ever since I was young, and have done mods for videogames I liked and played. It’s been my childhood dream to create worlds and stories, and coding is the best way to script events the way you want them to go. While this may not be exactly what I’m looking for, I think it’ll give me an accurate experience of what that life is like.</font>'
Story.append(Paragraph(ptext, styles["Justify"]))


doc.build(Story)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're going wrong but I recently did something very similar. I found this site [PdfGen](https://www.calazan.com/a-simple-python-program-for-exporting-a-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pdf-table-using-reportlab/)   which has a great example of what you are trying to do and if you follow it you will be able to create the template you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo - you used ” instead of " in line 26 (right double quotation mark instead of regular quotation mark).

Here's how the document looks like after fixing this:

[image: PDF Preview]

Comment: @phd - how is this not a valid answer? I just looked, and indeed, the OP has an invalid quote symbol. Kris states that he ran the code after fixing this, and got proper output. Is that not the case?

Comment: Sorry then. Without an additional information from the OP about his code raising SyntaxError it certainly is not an answer. It seems you two had a private conversation, hadn't you? (Kevin, not Kris, right?)

Comment: @phd - what private conversation??? Why would you even think that? I saw this in one of the review queues on the site while reviewing "first answers" from new users (I do a significant number of content reviews here).  The question, itself, is of poor quality (e.g. "why isn't my code working") and shows no output or error, but the answer provided, while arguably *could* have been a comment, might actually solve the OP's issue.